# Send JSON object from rails controller to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, spotify

So I have a hash that I built which looks something like this:

```
Track_list = {:track1=>{:url=>"https://open.spotify.com/track/2Oehrcv4Kov0SuIgWyQY9e", :name=>"Demons"},
 :track2=>{:url=>"https://open.spotify.com/track/0z8yrlXSjnI29Rv30RssNI", :name=>"Shots - Broiler Remix"},
 :track3=>{:url=>"https://open.spotify.com/track/6Ep6BzIOB9tz3P4sWqiiAB", :name=>"Radioactive"},
 :track4=>{:url=>"https://open.spotify.com/track/3I05foFixB2sSZvV5Ppty8", :name=>"Blank Space/Stand By Me - Medley / Live From Spotify London"},
 :track5=>{:url=>"https://open.spotify.com/track/4G8gkOterJn0Ywt6uhqbhp", :name=>"Radioactive"}}
```

And I am trying to convert that hash into a JSON so I can use it in my JS file and this is what I did in my controller:

```
@tl = track_list.as_json
# and it produces a result like this:
# {"track1"=>{"url"=>"https://open.spotify.com/track /2Oehrcv4Kov0SuIgWyQY9e", "name"=>"Demons"},
# "track2"=>{"url"=>"https://open.spotify.com/track/0z8yrlXSjnI29Rv30RssNI", "name"=>"Shots - Broiler Remix"},
# "track3"=>{"url"=>"https://open.spotify.com/track/6Ep6BzIOB9tz3P4sWqiiAB", "name"=>"Radioactive"},
# "track4"=>{"url"=>"https://open.spotify.com/track/3I05foFixB2sSZvV5Ppty8", "name"=>"Blank Space/Stand By Me - Medley / Live From Spotify London"},
# "track5"=>{"url"=>"https://open.spotify.com/track/4G8gkOterJn0Ywt6uhqbhp", "name"=>"Radioactive"}}
```

However, when I go to my JS file and try to print out the file, This is what I get:

```
console.log("<%= @tl %>");
"{&quot;track1&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://open.spotify.com/track/2Oehrcv4Kov0SuIgWyQY9e&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Demons&quot;},&quot;track2&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://open.spotify.com/track/0z8yrlXSjnI29Rv30RssNI&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Shots - Broiler Remix&quot;},&quot;track3&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://open.spotify.com/track/6Ep6BzIOB9tz3P4sWqiiAB&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Radioactive&quot;},&quot;track4&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://open.spotify.com/track/3I05foFixB2sSZvV5Ppty8&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Blank Space/Stand By Me - Medley / Live From Spotify London&quot;},&quot;track5&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://open.spotify.com/track/4G8gkOterJn0Ywt6uhqbhp&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Radioactive&quot;}}"
```

And when I try to do:

```
console.log(JSON.parse("<%= @tl %>");
```

It doesnt work. I also tried putting `j` in front of `@tl` and it gave me the error saying that hash cannot be used with gsub.

**Also, when I try to do this:**

```
@track_list = JSON.generate(@tl) # from above
```

I get this:

```
"{\"track1\":{\"url\":\"https://open.spotify.com/track/2Oehrcv4Kov0SuIgWyQY9e\",\"name\":\"Demons\"},\"track2\":{\"url\":\"https://open.spotify.com/track/0z8yrlXSjnI29Rv30RssNI\",\"name\":\"Shots - Broiler Remix\"},\"track3\":{\"url\":\"https://open.spotify.com/track/6Ep6BzIOB9tz3P4sWqiiAB\",\"name\":\"Radioactive\"},\"track4\":{\"url\":\"https://open.spotify.com/track/3I05foFixB2sSZvV5Ppty8\",\"name\":\"Blank Space/Stand By Me - Medley / Live From Spotify London\"},\"track5\":{\"url\":\"https://open.spotify.com/track/4G8gkOterJn0Ywt6uhqbhp\",\"name\":\"Radioactive\"}}"
```

So it's actually escaping everything correctly...I don't know why when I use the same variable in my JS file, it doesn't escape the quotes or anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send JSON object from Rails controller to Javascript by doing this:

```
console.log("<%= @tl.to_json.html_safe %>");
```

Comment: omg you're amazing. why does html_safe work? What does that actually do>

Comment: Sometimes, ERB might be escaping JSON because it thinks it's not html safe. So, it works when you use `html_safe` like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var my_obj = <%= j @tl %>;
console.log(my_obj);
```

You just have a couple minor issues.  You do need to use `escape_javascript` in your view (or its alias `j`).  But also you are sticking the json object between quotes, which will cause the browser to treat it like a string instead of a json object.